# Debugging gdb goes wild when stepping into printf

Tags: c, linux

I dont get the strange behavior of gdb when I do step and it goes to printf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
int main()
{
    printf("Hello");
}
```

The debugging loads libraries I dont get what happens. It writes hundreds of line, I have to ctrl F to find my printf !
What happens and how to prevent this ?

[Here is a picture of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYwjA.png)

Comment: Step over standard functions. If you step into them what do you expect?

Comment: Okay so that's the normal step thing to go through standard functions ? I just have to type continue when I see it goes there ?

Comment: simply step over. If you do not then you will step in. It is quite logical I believe

Comment: Yeah that's logical, but I would find even more logical to automatically ignore the standard functions when stepping and just go on with my normal program.
Is there an option to do so ?

Comment: @BenoitCastang The option to do so *is* the "step over"

Comment: As a GDB user I want to step over any function not interesting to my current debugging task, not only standard functions. And if I want to watch a standard function _and installed_ its source, I want to step into it. On other occasions I want to step into functions without a source, but at machine code level. All in the same debugging session. How could an option help here? This is the rational behind the different "step" commands.

Comment: Okay so stepping goes into the standard function, so have to type next to step over. That's ok, I'm beginning to undesrtand how debugging works, thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Benoit Castang. Please the error as text not an image.